# How to test array contains only objects with PHPUnit?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-testing

I'm looking for solution to test an array of objects with PHPUnit in my Laravel project.

This is my haystack array:

```php
[
    [
        "id" => 10,
        "name" => "Ten"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 5,
        "name" => "Five"
    ]
]
```

And this is the needles array:

```php
[
    [
        "id" => 5,
        "name" => "Five"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 10,
        "name" => "Ten"
    ]
]
```

The order of objects doesn't matter, also keys of objects doesn't matter. The only matter is we have two objects and all objects has exactly same keys and exactly same values.

What is the correct solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `assertContainsEquals` method like this:

```php
$haystack = [
    [
        'id' => 10,
        'name' => 'Ten'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Five'
    ]
];

$needles = [
    [
        'name' => 'Five',
        'id' => 5
    ],
    [
        'id' => 10,
        'name' => 'Ten'
    ]
];

foreach ($needles as $needle) {
    $this->assertContainsEquals($needle, $haystack);
}
```

You could also a create your own assert method if you intend to perform the assertion more often:

```php
public function assertContainsEqualsAll(array $needles, array $haystack): void
{
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        $this->assertContainsEquals($needle, $haystack);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but if I think right, it will give true if the haystack contains other elements too, right?

Comment: No, as soon as you add another key to either the haystack or one of the needles it will fail

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Roj Vroemen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080556/roj-vroemen)'s answer I implemented this solution for exact match asserting:

```php
    public function assertArrayContainsEqualsOnly(array $needles, array $haystack, string $context = ''): void
    {
        foreach ($needles as $index => $needle) {
            $this->assertContainsEquals(
                $needle,
                $haystack,
                ($context ? $context . ': ' : '') . 'Object not found in array.'
            );

            unset($haystack[$index]);
        }

        $this->assertEmpty(
            $haystack,
            ($context ? $context . ': ' : '') . 'Not exact match objects in array.'
        );
    }
```